# Do double sided GPIO headers exist?

Tags: gpio, pi-zero

I'm trying to attach two peripherals to a Pi Zero (no pin conflicts as far as I am aware), and I'd like to attach one peripheral to the front of the board and one to the back. Is there such a thing as a double sided GPIO header with pins pointing in both directions? I tried doing this myself with pins taken from a normal GPIO hammer header and it didn't go very well as the pins weren't long enough and I couldn't get the iron in between the pins properly.

Answer (score 5):

You might be interested in Stacking headers (eg: https://www.adafruit.com/product/85)

Several boards all with stacking headers can be connected on top of each other, including to a breadboard at the bottom of the stack too.

Photo example to illustrate, just an arbitrary google images result:
[image]

Answer (score 5):

Sure, longer pins do exist:

[image]

An alternative is to have male pins on one side and female pins on the other:

[image]

Searching for "GPIO 2x20" in your favorite shopping site should give you similar results.

In both cases, you may need an iron which is thin enough to go between the pins to make sure the solder flows evenly around each pin.

Answer (score 1):

You can get extended headers - I use these on my Pico so it plugs into a breadboard but still has accessible pins.

NOTE this will not let you use 2 HATs (as the pins would be inverted).

The normal solution is to use extended headers on the HAT.